# How can I programmatically show a ShareLink sheet with SwiftUI (4.0)

Tags: swiftui

This is how to implement in a view:

```
ShareLink(url) {
    Label("Share", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
}
```

How could I make this a programmatic experience?

Ex. Tap a button, do an async task, then show sharelink sheet when task is finished.

Answer (score 1):

In the example below, clicking the "Perform Task and Share" button initiates an asynchronous task simulated using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`. Once the task is completed, the `urlToShare` state variable is updated to a URL, and `isTaskCompleted` is set to true. The `.onChange` modifier detects the change in `isTaskCompleted` and sets `showShareSheet` to true, which triggers the ShareLink sheet to open.

Example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isTaskCompleted = false
    @State private var showShareSheet = false
    @State private var urlToShare: URL? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Perform Task and Share") {
                doAsyncTask {
                    // This is where the async task is completed
                    self.urlToShare = URL(string: "https://www.example.com")
                    self.isTaskCompleted = true
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showShareSheet) {
            if let url = urlToShare {
                ShareLink(item: url) {
                    Label("Share", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: isTaskCompleted) { _ in
            if isTaskCompleted {
                // Display the share sheet
                showShareSheet = true
            }
        }
    }

    func doAsyncTask(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // Simulating an async task
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```