# SwiftUI ShareLink on optional URL

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-sharelink

I want to use ShareLink to save a zipped backup file that needs to be generated in my code. I was able to do this in a clunky way and am looking for something more elegant.

My first way had a button that created the zipped file. When the button code succeeded a second part of the view would show up (as the optional URL variable wasn't nil anymore) that would show the ShareLink view to the user so they could export it. This was clunky and I wasn't sure when I should remove the local zipped file in a clean way and respectful to the user.

My new idea was to replace the ShareLink item (URL) with a function call BUT I don't know how to handle the condition if the URL is nil (zipping the file doesn't work). This works beautifully if I use "!" to force it but if I change my function, for testing, to return nil ONLY just to see what happens the program crashes on app load.

This is my sharelink code on my main view:

```
ShareLink(item: functionToBackupAndReturnURLifSuccessfulAndNilIfNot()!, label: {
       Label("Backup All Items", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up.on.square")
})
```

My simplified function:

```
private func functionToBackupAndReturnURLifSuccessfulAndNilIfNot() -> URL? {
    let optionalURL = ClassName().exportToFile(dataController: dataController)
    return optionalURL
}
```

If this function returns only nil then it crashes on program load with `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

```
private func functionToBackupAndReturnURLifSuccessfulAndNilIfNot() -> URL? {
    return nil
}
```

Is there anyway to make this work elegantly. I want the sharelink to be a simple button that kicks off the export code but gives an error to the user if the code export fails and shares the share sheet if successful.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really "show an error" when a user taps on a `ShareLink`. The best way I can think of is to make a regular button, do the export, show an error with an `.alert` if it fails, and show a share sheet with [the iOS 15 way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69892283/5133585) otherwise.

The "iOS 15 way" of course wraps a `UIActivityViewController`. There is currently no way around that. See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74916763/5133585) about showing a SwiftUI share sheet programmatically, which has no answers.

On the other hand, if you are fine with a sheet showing no share options when the export failed (instead of a more obvious "error" alert), you can create a `Transferable` value that can only be exported when the URL is not nil, e.g.

```
struct Backup: Transferable {
    
    let url: URL?
    
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(exportedContentType: .zip) { backup in
            SentTransferredFile(backup.url!)
        }.exportingCondition { $0.url != nil } // this makes the force unwrapping safe
    }
}
```

Then you can create your `ShareLink` like this, with a preview:

```
ShareLink(item: Backup(url: functionToBackupAndReturnURLifSuccessfulAndNilIfNot()), preview: .init("Backup"))
```

Comment: It compiles but was called several times (7 or 8) and rather than sharing the zip file at that URL shared a data file with no extension.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the "iOS 15 way" as I have a slightly less clunky method using that for now. Going to leave the question open for a bit in case there's another way before closing it. :)

Comment: I did. When I go to open it it tells me "the operation couldn't be completed. Inappropriate file type or format." Plus the file size is too small :) The other ways helps me progress for now. Thanks

Comment: @Kyra Huh, that sounds like your export code is problematic. That `ClassName()` call looks suspicious. Did you mean to export an existing instance of `ClassName` instead of a new instance? Anyway, I've edited to use a `FileRepresentation` (which I forgot about) instead. Now it shouldn't call your export function multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Going with a different approach but this got me over the hump. Implemented you changes and it only calls it once but it's when the app opens and not when I press the button.